# Adding data to v-text-field from axios response

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How can I assign the value retrieved from axios to `v-text-field`

I have this in my template:

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="name"
   label="Name"></v-text-field>

    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          name: '' // <= how will I assign the value here from axios response?
        }
      },
      asyncData ({ params }) {
        return axios.get(`my-url`)
        .then((response) => {
          return { user: response.data.data.results[0] };
        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you call `asyncData()`?

Comment: @ittus It's automatically called when the vue page loaded. I can also get the results from response. What I would like to do is assign the user's name to data() name attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `created` hook?

```
created() {
   this.name = this.user.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Husam Ibrahim

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using NUXT (from the `asyncData` method).

The data you return from the `asyncData` method is merged into the data of your component.

You should do the following:

```
<template>
    <v-text-field
            v-model="name"
            label="Name"></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        asyncData ({ params }) {
            return axios.get(`my-url`).then((response) => {
                return { name: response.data.data.results[0].name };
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: On my terminal I keep getting 

✖ error TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined